# Is there a way to call GROUP BY as a variable within a calculated field in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions, azure-databricks, sql-date-functions

i am trying to sort by the year as my calculated field is not correct when trying to graph by date. i think if i get the date to be in chronological order then my problem will be solved but i'm not sure how to do that. My dateIn field is in the format "7/10/2022"

```
SELECT 
  i.dateIn, 
  i.productId, 
  i.docNumber,
  b.batchTotalCount,
  i.productInCount,
  b.batchTotalCount - COALESCE(SUM(i.productInCount) OVER(PARTITION BY i.productId,i.docNumber ORDER BY i.productInDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW),0) AS CurrentQuantity_warehouse

FROM 
  product_batch  as b
   JOIN product_in AS i ON i.productId = b.productId AND i.docNumber = b.docNumber

ORDER BY year(i.dateIn),month(i.dateIn),day(i.dateIn) asc
```

I tried putting the long order by field in the last line but it didn't work. If it helps I am using Azure Databricks.

Comment: _Column_ dateIn data type?

Comment: My dateIn field is in the format "7/10/2022" --- Dates don't have a format in a database, they are just dates that you can output in any format you want. Hopefully, you are not storing the date in a column of a string data type. The format "7/10/2022" is ambiguous anyway, it may mean October 7 or July 10.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
SUM(i.productInCount) OVER (PARTITION BY i.productId, i.docNumber
                                ORDER BY i.productInDate)
```

You are building a running total. But as you

```
ORDER BY year(i.dateIn), month(i.dateIn), day(i.dateIn) ASC
```

or just

```
ORDER BY i.dateIn
```

for that matter, your result will look mixed up.

Typically you would want to show the same order in your result rows, so you see the totals building up:

```
ORDER BY i.productId, i.docNumber, i.productInDate
```